# Oracle says column ambiguously defined but all columns fully qualified

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two schemas, `SCHEMA1` and `SCHEMA2`. They both contain a table called `TBL`, and the DDL for `TBL` is *completely identical* in both schemas.

This is my query:

```
         SELECT SCHEMA1.TBL.PK_COL source_pk, SCHEMA2.TBL.PK_COL master_pk
           FROM SCHEMA1.TBL
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA2.TBL
             ON SCHEMA1.TBL.PK_COL = SCHEMA2.TBL.PK_COL
          WHERE SCHEMA1.TBL.PK_COL <= :pk_col_source_ceil
            AND SCHEMA1.TBL.MODIFY_DT >= :modify_dt_source_floor
            AND SCHEMA1.TBL.MODIFY_DT > SCHEMA2.TBL.MODIFY_DT - :modify_dt_source_lag    
/
```

When I run it, Oracle complains:

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

But I have explicitly fully qualified the columns everywhere. Why does Oracle hate me?

My Oracle version is 11.2.0.4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reproduced error:

```
09/12/2015 18:46:45:SQL> SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

09/12/2015 18:46:45:SQL> SELECT schema1.tbl.pk_col source_pk, schema2.tbl.pk_col master_pk
  2    FROM schema1.tbl
  3    LEFT OUTER JOIN schema2.tbl ON schema1.tbl.pk_col = schema2.tbl.pk_col
  4   WHERE schema1.tbl.pk_col <= 10
  5         AND schema1.tbl.modify_dt >= SYSDATE
  6         AND schema1.tbl.modify_dt > schema2.tbl.modify_dt - 1;
       AND schema1.tbl.modify_dt > schema2.tbl.modify_dt - 1
           *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Tested with aliases and it works.

```
09/12/2015 18:56:09:SQL> SELECT T1.PK_COL source_pk, T2.PK_COL master_pk
  2             FROM SCHEMA1.TBL T1
  3  LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA2.TBL T2
  4               ON T1.PK_COL = T2.PK_COL
  5            WHERE T1.PK_COL <= 10--:pk_col_source_ceil
  6              AND T1.MODIFY_DT >= sysdate --:modify_dt_source_floor
  7              AND T1.MODIFY_DT > T2.MODIFY_DT - 1--:modify_dt_source_lag
  8  /

no rows selected
```

The docs state:

> If two or more tables have some column names in common, and if you are
>   specifying a join in the FROM clause, then you must qualify column
>   names with names of tables or table aliases.

Interestingly, only table aliases work when the table names themselves are in common. Schema names don't cut it here.

[Oracle Docs reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm)

Comment: Have you tried without the aliases?  It will work. There is something else going on in OP's question.

Comment: yep I did. Edited above

Comment: Interesting. I tried on Oracle 12, and I don't get the error. Thanks for adding the edit.